# Is it a good practice to use 'd' when defining double literals in Java?

Tags: java, double, literals

Hi if I want to define double literal I wrote:

```
(1) double a = 12.0;
```

but when I define double without something after decimal point, for example

```
(2) double b=12;
```

is it more acceptable to use

```
(3) double c=12d;
```

instead?

From what I know (1) is the best way, If I can ask you what is the next better way to declare double literals which will be your choice and why?

Comment: For verbosity's sake, I use `12.0d` or `(double) 12.0`.

Comment: 1 and 3 are both preferable to 2, as they imply an intent for the number to be a double when viewed. You can also hard-cast it to double, but that turns into a lot of parentheses sometimes.

Comment: @qix: that seems both verbose and unnecessary.

Comment: This is a matter of taste and opinion. When compiled these literals will probably all be converted into doubles

Comment: You question is not only asking for opinions, its also ambigous. You talk about *double literal*, yet in example 2 there is no double literal. You're mixing up terms.

Comment: (2) is not a `double` literal but an `int` literal that's converted to `double` at compiling.

Comment: @Compass Matter of personal preference. For someone like me that jumps between several languages at any given time, the extra verbosity is always nice.

Comment: @Qix I have no problem with how you do yours. That was someone else who voiced his concerns.

Comment: @Compass whoops, you're right; sorry :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Java language Specification:

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d.
>
> The floating point types (float and double) can also be expressed
>   using E or e (for scientific notation), F or f (32-bit float literal)
>   **and D or d (64-bit double literal; this is the default and by convention is omitted)**.

```
double d1 = 123.4;
// same value as d1, but in scientific notation
double d2 = 1.234e2;
float f1  = 123.4f;
```

So adding `D` or `d` is the same thing as omitting as you already know, but I would say that it is better to follow the convention and omit it.

Comment: +1 for quoting the spec. For future answers, backticks are for inline code; use 4 spaces for code blocks (as it enables syntax highlighting). While I don't agree with your opinion personally, the spec never lies. :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter. There is no difference whatsoever. 
The default type is `double`. So unless you place an `f` (if you want to treat the value as a float) the value is treated as double by default.
It is the same thing as with integers. Default type is `int`. If you want a `long` you have to add an `l` otherwise everything is an `int`.

Comment: There is a different, though. Number 2 doesn't start as a double.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler sugar. I use option 2 the most, but if i want to enforce calculation result i use option 3.

```
   int intval = ...
   double intdev = 1 / intval;
   double doubledev = 1d / intval;
```

Comment: Note I do not actually use Magic values other then in temporary custom tests.